# Where can I write a complaint about overeager downvoters in a particular tag?

Tags: support, voting

Someone always downvotes questions with the [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) tag. This occurs too fast after posting; I suspect it is done automatically.

I have asked about this problem on https://t.me/modernperl Telegram channel. People also can confirm this: often downvoting

Where can I write a complaint, or maybe ask moderators to check?

Comment: ask moderators to check what? Ask long as no single user is being targetted everyone is free to vote in whatever way they like on whatever post they like.

Comment: I don't know about the perl tag, but the java tag has many quickly downvoted questions, too. I rarely see unjustified ones, often downvoted ones are beginner or homework questions without any research. Do you have perl examples?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49672521/4632019

Comment: Why, in your opinion, are the downvotes in that example question undeserved? Does the question, for example, show any preliminary research?

Comment: @EugenKonkov Ok, you just edited it. The downvotes came before that, I'd suspect lack of research.

Comment: @ModusTollens: despite on how question is fine. It is downvoted. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48277764/4632019, Also you may look at different my questions with tag perl

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49663071/what-is-null-vk-in-perl) question is very recent, tagged perl, and has no downvotes.

Comment: @yivi: Look at previous questions with `perl` tag of that author

Comment: So, if we find a question that isn't downvoted, this breaks your theory of "automated downvotes". My current theory is "questions maybe aren't as good as you think they may be".... (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658850/lwp-get-works-but-put-returns-401 is 17 hours old and no downvotes. So it can't be automated for every question.) Therefore I will stick to my theory. Most questions aren't great quality, regardless of tags...

Comment: I check all (not deleted) question in the perl tag for the last two day to see how many questions have to following properties: Exactly one Downvote and at least one upvote (aka a user downvoted a good question). Questions asked: 32, Questions that have this pattern: 2. I don't see any indication that a user downvotes all (or a large number of) questions according to your description in the perl tag in the last 2 days.

Comment: One downvote and one upvote could be equally well described as a bad question that someone is giving sympathy upvotes to. All depends on your point of view.

Comment: There are over 27,000 people who follow the Perl tag specifically. The assumption that there is some automated downvote of new questions is too big a claim to be taken seriously without some kind of data backing it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Assumption**

There are one or many users in the `perl` tag that downvote a majority of all questions.

**Check**

Because I was curious if this assumption can be proofed (and because I was bored), I wrote a [data explorer script](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/835563/questions-with-one-downvote-and-multiple-upvotes-per-tag) that searches for questions with the following properties: Exactly one downvote, at least one upvote. Although simplified, this should give an estimate of questions that are downvoted by a single person but are considered good questions by others.

This shows the following results

```
Month     | Questions Total | Question with properties |  Ratio
March     |       338       |            45            | 13.31%
February  |       254       |            36            | 14.17%
January   |       261       |            55            | 21.07%
```

**Conclusion**

The data show no indication that there would be a large number of questions that get downvoted in the `perl` tag.

Comment: >`Invalid column name 'perl'. Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date` http://joxi.ru/brRjbK6HQwyaRr

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it very error-safe: Check if you provided the parameters like this: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/835572/questions-with-one-downvote-and-multiple-upvotes-per-tag?TagName=%27perl%27&From=%272018-03-01%27&To=%272018-04-01%27

Answer (score 9):

Generally speaking, unless you suspect a user is abusing their votes by targeting a particular user (or part of a voting ring, or operating a sock puppet; or another kind of fraudulent activity), all votes are valid and users are free to cast them as they see fit. Hopefully following the [guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote), but there is no "vote audit process".

That being said, I think that your claim that there is a user automatically down-voting every perl question is suspect to say the least.

Comment: the question were about where to claim. Is there a way to check my suspect

Comment: There is no way to "check your suspect", votes are anonymous. And there is no avenue to complain, besides what you are doing here.

Comment: @EugenKonkov requests of 'appeals', 'reviews' and the like have come up before.  It's difficult to estimate how much such a scheme would cost and so how much users would have to pay for the appeal/whatever.  Since an appellant is effectively asking for time from professional SO staff, I suspect that they would have to put up at least $100 up-front just to lodge an appeal and have some CM skim through it.  Sometimes, I suspect that some users think that such a service could be provided for free - lol.